# Rails ActionView::Template::Error: after asset compile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compiler-errors, asset-pipeline, assets

i am working on a story that seemed to irritate some of our tests on Circle CI so i jusmped on the case, only to find the tests on my machine where failing for different things namely i forgot to compile the assets. i then tried to compiled my assets like this

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

which failed

```
rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter
```

then realised i should run

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development
```

this passed fine but when running my test suit, my tests just all where going red all over the place

throwing out

```
Failure/Error: visit login_page
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `paid?' for nil:NilClass
```

i tried re-raking my db, re-compiling my assets and nothing seems to get it going again?

its so wierd because these tests where fine before i compiled the assets? but from what i can see all the other solutions for this `ActionView::Template::Error:` error is to compile ones assets but mine are?

Comment: the error points to your database configuration. have you fixed that?

Comment: yeah there is nothing wrong with my database config

Comment: you need to look at where you're getting the error.  the error says that you're calling paid? on a nil object which is most probably an instance variable that wasn't set.

Comment: thanks dude i figured it out thanks for running through it with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i lost my temper and started throwing my toys out the cot! and tried reseting my db luckily i started with my test db.

i ran `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:reset` and then realised that if i `test:prepare` then it wont seed. and somehow somewhere my test:db must have droped its seeds? but now its working

thanks and sorry for making a question without trying everything.